# Angular2: Scrollbar hide on use router.navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, scrollbar

Im developing a fairly normal web application using Angular2. I've run into an annoying problem: From time to time scrolling up and down does not work.

There is no errors or anything to indicate why this problems occurs. Only solution is to refresh the page, and scrolling will work again. This problem has been observed in all major browsers (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox).

Does anyone know what might be the root of this problem? and on use of `this.router.navigate()` the navigated page has no scrollbar until i refresh the page manually.

Comment: Firstly, use web developer tool of browser and look at the <body> tag. If the content is higher than browser window but no scrollbar appear, the body might be set to overflow: hidden, and find what make it. In case you use any calculation on <body> height, you need to call it each time you navigate to new component's view.

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. my issue was there wee popups which i used, using ngxsmartmodal. After closing needed to remove it which i was not doing.